# How to turn off response caching in remote jQuery validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have such problem:

I'm using jQuery validation plugin to check login credentials. If user enters incorrect email but correct password for this user and push submit - validation fails. Then user enters correct email - request is sending with THE SAME PREVIOUS PARAMATERS.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
$("#user_email").change(function(){
$("#user_email").removeData("previousValue");
});
...jQuery validation code ...
$(".login").validate({
    rules: {
        "user[email]":{
            email: true,
            required: true
        },
         'user[password]': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            remote: {
             url: url_name.concat("checkpass"),
    //url: "http://91.228.126.168:3000/checkpass",
            type: "get",
            data: {
              email: function() { return $("#user_email").val(); 
              }
            }

          }
        }
    }
    })
```

I can't get what I'm doing wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#user_password").change(function(){
 // alert('user_password')
$("#user_email").removeData("previousValue");
$("#user_password").removeData("previousValue");
 });

   $("#user_email").change(function(){
  //alert('user_email')
$("#user_email").removeData("previousValue");
$("#user_password").removeData("previousValue");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use post instead of get. Post is never cached. Get is always cached.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup) function, has a '**cache**' parameter that allows you to configure jQuerys behavior regarding caching.